Locate point in a global system within a bearing plot
I have a data frame with the x and y coordinates of the trees recorded in the field. I also have the longitude and latitude of the plot's corners recorded with the global GNSS.
My plot is not aligned with the Ouest-East and South-North directions. They are inclined (see the screenshot attached).
I would like to know how I can locate my trees in a global system by taking into account the inclination of the plot.
I converted the coordinates of my corners in UTM 34S, and I add the x and y of each tree to find their coordinates in a global system, however many points were outside of the plot as my plot is inclined. I have tried to find the angle of inclination by this formula
# coordinate of the corners de GPS01 (south-west corner) et GPS02 (north-west corner)
gps01 <- c(365648.8342, 7985404.999)
gps02 <- c(365637.2736, 7985427.049)

# Calculate the angle of décalage in  radians
angle_decalage_rad <- atan2(gps02[1] - gps01[1], gps02[2] - gps01[2])

# convert the angle in degree
angle_decalage_deg <- angle_decalage_rad * (180 / pi)

rotation_matrix <- matrix(c(cos(angle_decalage_rad), -sin(angle_decalage_rad), 
                           sin(angle_decalage_rad), cos(angle_decalage_rad)), 
                         ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)

# Appliquer la rotation aux coordonnées des arbres
coords_rotated <- st_coordinates(sf_field_ov_H1_GNSS) %*% rotation_matrix

# Créer un objet sf avec les nouvelles coordonnées
new_geometries <- st_sfc(lapply(1:nrow(coords_rotated), function(i) {
  st_point(c(coords_rotated[i, 1], coords_rotated[i, 2]))
}))


If I understand correctly, you need to convert your X,Y coordinates to EPSG:4326 as well? Are X and Y relative to plot corner? if yes, calculate their position accordingly and convert the whole data frame to EPSG:4326.
Would you mind to expand your question with subset of your data, please? It may help others to find a proper solution.

Do you have a rectangular plot which is not aligned to the UTM coordinate system? To work out the rotation of the plot relative to UTM you need more than just two opposite corners, since that doesn't uniquely identify a rectangle. Do you have all four corner (x,y) coordinates?

However, if your plot is perfectly square then any two diagonal corners do define a unique square, and then you can work out the rotation to align with the UTM axis. But if your plot is a rectangle, then two corners are not enough.

my plot is a rectangle. See the coordinate of my corners
Point Id Point Role                     Easting Northing
GPS01 GNSSPhaseMeasuredPP 365648.8342 7985404.999
GPS02 GNSSPhaseMeasuredPP 365637.2736 7985427.049
GPS03 GNSSPhaseMeasuredPP 365740.5026 7985443.331
GPS04 GNSSPhaseMeasuredPP 365729.8003 7985465.942
What I want to do is to convert my xy coordinates to UTM 34S or even EPSG: 4326 but I prefer UTM 34S as the coordinates of corners are already in UTM 34S.
My rectangular plot is not perfectly parallel with the South-North and West-East directions.

And the trees are measured in X-Y coordinates starting at the bottom corner of the plot? Why don't your four points on the image in the question line up with the corners of the plot?

Assuming that GPS01 is your origin for your tree coordinates, and that the line GPS01 to GPS03 is your tree X axis, and GPS01 to GPS02 is your tree Y axis, I have code to transform measurements in that coordinate system to UTM34S. But you need to clarify that's what your tree location measurements are, and that those points are the reference points and lines for this. Basically its rotate about 22 degrees and add the origin.

Hello Spacedman, Yes I confirm that the GPS01 and GPS03 is my tree X axis and GPS01 to GPS02 is my Y axis.  Yet, the trees are measured in x-y coordinates starting at the GPS01 corner.
See the example of tree my x and y coordinates
x_coord = c(0.81,2.3,2.54,2.7,2.26,2.85,3.26)
y_coord = c(1.52,6.1,6.6,7.13,7.43,7.21,7.04)

Why my four points on the image in the question dont line up with the corners of the plot? The reason is that the corner of the plot was measured using the GPS receptor Garmin 64 while the four corners was taken using GNSS. I used GNSS to locate and align my Terrestrial lidar data which was taken few days after I set up the plot and recorded manually the trees
